# color image to grayscale image not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

As [this](http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS) I'm using this

```
img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;/*ie fallback*/
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

It works in chrome. But not working in firefox. I'm using firefox 27.1.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7fE8/)

Comment: `To gain the same effect in Firefox 4+, we need to use an SVG filter` - you need to add the SVG filter - `filter: url(filter.svg#greyscale);` - and then create `filter.svg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I should note that CSS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) is an experimental technology which is only implemented in Webkit, and it doesn't have browser compatibility.

However, for Firefox 3.5+, you could use [SVG filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) and [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/data_URIs) for the SVG.

As we have to target the `filter` element (by `#grayscale` in this case), we shouldn't [encode the SVG as base64](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php).

Hence we can encode the space characters as `%20` to get the Data URI to work:

```css
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

Here you go:

```css
img {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

img:hover {  /* Remove the filter on hover. remove this if it is not needed */
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```